# flexbox Выравнивание текста

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Как выровнять ссылку по центру flex-элемента?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Родитель ссылки:

```
.footer {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;

padding-bottom: 30px; }
```

Стилизация ссылки:

```
.paragraph-link {
text-decoration: none;
color: black; }

.paragraph-link:hover {
text-decoration: underline; }
```

Comment: Добавил данные в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно на вашем скрине не текст, а ссылка.

```css
.flex {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  display: flex;
  justify-items: center;
}

a {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <a href="#">Какой-то текст</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй

```
justify-content: center
```